# How does a hobby ESC drive a BLDC motor?

Tags: inverter, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

**Background**: I'm an aerospace engineer modeling the electrical systems of a standard quadcopter. I came across a lot of technically-inadequate or incorrect material while researching the humble yet technically-rich electronic speed controller (ESC), so I thought I'd collect my newfound knowledge for posterity and further corrections by the community.

*Thank you*, Bruce Abbott, for your clear explanations. I hope I didn't misunderstand them!

**Questions**:

1. How does a hobby aircraft ESC drive a BLDC motor? Does it use PWM?
2. How does the ESC measure back-EMF to calculate speed?

Comment: Stack exchange sites are reserved only for *specific* questions.  "How does xxx work" is not a specific question and hence not suited to this format, instead it is something for which you need a different type of internet site or reference.

Comment: Hold on, don't delete my post! Let me re-word the question that sent me down this rabbit hole.

Comment: Even after the revision, this remains both too broad, and amply and *accurately* covered in hobby references - including of course the *actual source code* of the well known and market-leading open source implementations.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Do share this material! As a newcomer to the world of electronics, I gravitated to posts in EE.SE rather than hobby or textbook references because hobby references were too applied ("ESCs use PWM" without a hint of PWM inversion) and textbook references were too theoretical or outright non-existent. I'd rather try to edit and improve my Q&A to community standards than face a closure as you yourself argued in your meta [post](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/770/why-are-we-so-strict-with-closing-questions-cant-we-just-keep-them-open/909#909)

Comment: Your question is not only too broad as a matter of rules, it is misdirected as a matter of practicality.  **The applicable expertise is simply not here** - rather it is with the authors of the leading ESC firmwares, whose published work you will have no trouble locating in the appropriate places.  If you haven't yet looked, then you need to stop ignoring that domain expertise.  If you do decide to ask a question here *after* reviewing that, it must be one which is narrow enough to be *specifically answerable* per the rules here.

Comment: I see your point, but why not let this post stand as a "wiki" with corrections from more knowledgeable users? I don't see how that could harm future visitors who seek something more technical than Hobby references and not so technical as ESC firmware. Even if you're trying to learn ESC firmware, wouldn't this be a good overview? It's like professors who dove straight into theory on day 1 of class without giving a big-picture overview of the topic at hand. No context for the deeper dives!

Comment: Stack Exchange sites are very intentional **not** to serve the purpose of introduction to or overview of a subject.  That's the exact opposite of their purpose.  Rather, they are for picking up with narrow specifics that introductory overviews elsewhere do not handle.

Comment: Alright then, fade me. I no longer fear death. At least the post forced me to really think about the hardware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimers**

1. This post assumes the reader is roughly familiar with how the electromagnet and phase energization inside BLDC motors generates motion. I use the term "phase" rather interchangeably.
2. The actual *control* algorithm for sensorless control is beyond the scope of this post. I don't have a firm understanding of that yet.

---

**Note regarding "AC" vs "DC" motors**: technically, *all* motors are AC motors because an alternating current is required to switch the polarity of the electromagnets inside the motor and pull/push the rotor magnets to generate torque.

A "brushed DC" motor is the *only* motor that will run when connected directly to DC power because a mechanical apparatus called a *commutator* will passively switch the direction of the current *inside* the magnet. The battery still sees a DC current (aka commutation). The dark/light blue rings in this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPmIu.jpg) are commutators.

Every other motor, including brushless "DC" motors (BLDC), <s>are now enemies of the Republic</s> will **not** run when connected directly to a DC source as they require active commutation and some sort of speed or position feedback to control the commutation.

---

**Overview**: The drive train of a hobby aircraft typically consists of a battery (DC power source), an ESC (motor driver), and a brushless "DC" motor, aka BLDC motor (2-phase *AC* motor). The ESC provides two functions:

1. DC/AC inversion: six switches serve as [PWM inverters](http://www.ewh.ieee.org/soc/es/Nov1998/08/PWMINV.HTM) that convert the DC power supplied by the battery into AC voltage for a motor.
2. Position sensing: 9 resistors ([detailed paper](http://cache.freescale.com/files/product/doc/AN1914.pdf)) sense per-phase voltages (and indirectly rotor position & speed) for the control algorithm.

Below is a diagram of the 6 switches (excluding zero-detection elements) that perform the core function of PWM inversion in an ESC:

[image: phase circuitry]

PWM inversion and position sensing enable an ESC to correctly energize 2/3 phases of a BLDC motor to generate torque while using the 3rd phase for position *and* speed feedback *without* the use of an external sensor.

---

**Key motor property: Back-EMF**. The following model describes a BLDC motor's response to an applied voltage (\$V_a\$):

$$V_{a} = 2I_{a}R_{a} + E_{line-to-line} = 2I_{a}R_{a} + k_{e}\omega$$

Where voltage and current are per-phase peak values, \$[k_{e}] = V/\frac{rad}{s}\$, \$R_{a}\$ is the resistance of a single phase, and \$\omega\$ is the angular speed of the rotor in rad/s.

**As a motor spins faster, an increasingly greater "back-voltage" builds up inside the motor.** This reverse potential is called back-EMF (E), and generators rely on this potential to convert mechanical energy into electrical energy. The speed at which \$E = V_a\$ defines the maximum electrical speed of the motor since the power source <s>has lost the high ground</s> can no longer force more voltage down the line. This electrical speed limit is *typically* above the mechanical speed limit from bearings, mechanical stresses, etc. Nevertheless, I think direct-drive torquers (see [here](http://www.npm-ht.co.jp/products/documents/KBM_79_Frameless_Motors.pdf) for motors with \$k_e\$ > 2 N*m/A!) are actually limited by electrical speed since they have such large \$k_e\$ values (\$k_e = k_t = 1/k_v\$ with the right [units](http://learningrc.com/motor-kv/)).

BLDC ESCs "massage" rotor speed and position information out of the back-EMF voltage without the need of an external sensor for position feedback. This saves weight, power, and mechanical complexity.

---

**PWM inversion**: Depending on the user's throttle ratio (\$d\$), the ESC will use pulse-width-modulation (PWM) to generate a trapezoidal driving voltage of varying peak value (\$V_p = dV_{dc}\$) for the motor. This output PWM power signal (f is in the kHz) is **completely** different from the PWM (aka pulse "position" modulation) control signal (f = 50 Hz) that handles RC communication (more info on the [latter](https://www.princeton.edu/~mae412/TEXT/NTRAK2002/292-302.pdf)). The PWM signals between the ESC and motor are *much* more fascinating.

Depending on the phase combination to be energized, the power PWM signal will:

1. "ramp up" the peak line-to-line voltage seen by the motor using ever-higher ON-times for the base pulses. This corresponds to the up-slope of the trapezoidal drive voltage.
2. "hold" the peak voltage steady at the desired throttle setting (\$V_p = dV_{dc}\$). This corresponds to the flat-top of the drive trapezoid.
3. "ramp down" the peak voltage. This corresponds to the down-slope.

See my rough annotation below (original image courtesy of [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-do-the-commutation-waveforms-look-like-for-a-brushless-motor) Q&A on Robotics SE), and how gates will hold HI for increasingly longer periods of time (ramp up), hold HI for a long period (flat-top), and hold HI for decreasingly lower periods of time (ramp down). Negative energization just corresponds to different phase pairs.

[image: gate waveforms]

Note, the duration of the flat-top region will increase/decrease as the motor speed decreases/increases because the ESC must energize pairs less/more frequently. In context of the PWM deep dive I cited earlier, this frequency change corresponds to a change in the PWM control frequency, not the more basic triangle wave frequency. The humble hobby ESC is a variable frequency drive!

---

**Position sensing**: Recall the back-EMF (E) generated by spinning motors. E "crawls back up all pipes" While the ESC energizes 2/3 phases. The instantaneous value of E depends on the rotor's position relative to an activated phase. If the rotor is instantaneously directly aligned with a phase, then e(t) is actually zero (no magnetic interactions).

If a phase isn't energized by the ESC's applied voltage, such as the 3rd phase *or* the other 2 phases when their drive circuits are open (OFF-time of PWM), then E is an opposing potential on those phases. If we measure E, then we can watch for when E crosses 0V. This zero-crossing corresponds to when the rotor passes a currently energized phase which indicates that the next set of electromagnets/phase combination should be energized (see [gif](https://i.makeagif.com/media/9-26-2015/Ciypjx.gif)).

*However*, there is a problem: the typical "wye" (Y) connection used in BLDC motors (pic below) doesn't have a neutral point, so what does the ESC actually *measure* back-EMF with respect to? The Y-midpoint isn't an output on most motors...

[image: wye connection]

The solution is to create 3 "virtual center taps" with another set of wye-resistors for each pair of opposing MOSFETs on the ESC as pictured below. These virtual grounds can serve as reference points for measuring E because the sum of line-to-line voltages in a proper wye connection is *always* zero (see how the traffic doesn't stop in this nifty [gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/3-phase_flow.gif)).
[image: basidrive]

Now the ESC actually has a meaningful method with which to measure EMF and sense the position and speed of the rotor.